# Не устанавливаются пакеты mysql и mysqldb

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, pip, package

Всех приветствую!
Итак я пытаюсь подключиться к удаленной БД MYSQL используя SQLAlchemy

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:pass@ip/db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Проблема заключается в том что я не могу установить пакеты который необходимы для подключения к БД (mysql и mysqldb)

При установки пакета mysql получаю ответ

```
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient (from mysql)
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/2k/Desktop/Project5/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/2k/Desktop/Project5/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/2k/Desktop/Project5/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/7d/l06jj60135s008gjr4rpm_dc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ojilqlm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/7d/l06jj60135s008gjr4rpm_dc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ojilqlm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/7d/l06jj60135s008gjr4rpm_dc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ojilqlm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

А при установке пакета mysqldb ответ следующий

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

Очень надеюсь, что подскажите решение ...

Comment: Читайте документацию по установке https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Спасибо!
Это помогло.